# where to format and map this array in the child component in ES6?

Tags: reactjs, es6-class

So I am getting a prop from a parent component. let's say that attribute has a data structure like the following: [{a: "a", b:"b"}, {c:"c", d:"d"}...]

And this is the component that gets this prop.

```
class Child extends Component {
    constructore(props){
       super();
       this.state = {items: []} 
       // props.name {a: "a", b: "b"}
    }
    render(){
       return( 

    )
  }
}
```

Now before I render that in the child component I would like to map this  into something else like

```
for (let key in names){
    items.push(<MenuItem value={names[key]}
    key={key} primaryText={names[key]} />);
}
```

the end result would be.

```
 class Child extends Component {
   constructore(props){
     super();
      this.state = {items: [<MenuItem value={"a"}>, 
     <MenuItem value{"b"},....etc   
}
  render(){
     return( 

   )
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like the following
I'm modifying your array to be

```
[{key: "a", value:"b"}, {key:"c", value:"d"}...]
```

I hope this requisite is ok to change and would still apply to your challenge

```
class Child extends Component {
   constructor(props){
     super(props);
   }
   render(){
     return this.props.items.map((item)=> {
       return <MenuItem key={item.key} value={item.value}/>;
     })
   }
}
```

This is generally a good react pattern. Use it everywhere :)